# Urlrewriter redirect for subdomains

Tags: asp.net

I am using the rewriter from urlrewriter.net to do redirection of pages and potentially subdomains from a website.

It is simple to setup and working for regular pages like:

```
<rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/blah.aspx" to="~/here.aspx" />
</rewriter>
```

I would like to use the same functionality to redirect subdomains as well.  I think this is available through this urlrewriter I am just having trouble getting it to function properly.

I would like a redirect to occur if they attempted to access abc.xyz.com to bring them to xyz.com/abc.aspx.

Anyone have any experience with this or could offer any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure that URL rewriting is going to pick up subdomains, unless the subdomain points to the same website as the main domain.

Comment: All subdomains current point to the main domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used redirection from IIS to accomplish this.  Couldn't get it to work otherwise.